# Efficient multiplication of a matrix and a "list of matrices" in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, optimization, matrix, matrix-multiplication

I want to compute the following matrix

`M(i,j)=sum_(k,l) c(k,l) kron(N(:,:,k),N(:,:,l))`

where the first two indices of `N` are the number of rows and columns (equal in this case), the last index denotes that I have a family of matrices `N`, and the matrix `c` is just a matrix of coefficients. Indices `k` and `l` run from 1 to 50 (in my specific case).

To do so, I have implemented the following algorithm:

```
c=randn(50,50);
N=randn(26,26,50);
M=zeros(size(N,1)^2);
for k=1:size(N,3)
for l=1:size(N,3)
M=M+c(k,l).*kron(N(:,:,k),N(:,:,l));
end
end
```

There is some funny thing with this code that I cannot figure out why it happens:

Say that I truncate the sum in `k` until, say, a finite number `n`. The difference in time between the computation when `k` goes from 1 to `n` and when it goes from 1 to `n+1` is much higher (around and order of magnitude) than the time that takes to compute just the matrix indexed by `k=n+1` and sum it to the total matrix computed up to `k=n`.

My questions are: is there a more efficient way of computing the matrix I am looking for? And what is going wrong with this algorithm?

Thank you very much.

Comment: `zeros(n)` create a 2D square matrix of dimension nxn, so in your example you create M, a 2D matrix but you try to access a third dimension with `M(:,:,k)`

Comment: @obchardon Pretty sure that was a typo in his code.  Alex - Check my edit.

Comment: @Alex Your formula doesn't exactly match your code. So first, can you confirm that your current code above produces the correct expected output? Only then should you think about optimizing/vectorizing those loops..

Comment: @Amro the only thing that is missing is the input matrix `c` and the family of input matrices `N`. For the rest, the code is exactly what I am running. You can put your preferred matrices, but I'm adding some now for reference.

Comment: @Alex no I meant the sum expression doesn't look right in the formula, plus you have `(i,j)` that are never expressed on the right hand side.. Your code accumulates the matrix in each iteration, I wasn't sure if you wanted that vs. summing over all items to get one scalar result at each iteration and storing that scalar value in `M(i,j)`. Makes sense?

Comment: @Amro My apologies, I come from a physics background and I tend to write the subindices of the matrix, and I was trying to make in that first line more a "formula" thing instead of a pseudocode. However, the algorithm does what it should do, i.e., output a matrix.

Comment: @Alex ok. A first idea is that you can reduce the double-loop into one. Note that `[kron(A,C); kron(B,C)]` is the same as `kron([A;B],C)`. So you can probably concatenate all slices `N(:,:,k)` into one tall matrix, and multiply that by each slice `N(:,:,l)` in one loop instead of two. You would then split them back and accumulate.

Answer (score 2):

*TL;DR: this turned out to be slower than your code, I just wanted to share what I tried anyway...*

---

Below is an implementation of the idea I mentioned in the comments (`funcAmro`), compared with your original code (`funcAlex`):

```
function [t,v] = testKron()
    s1 = 26;
    s3 = 50;
    c = randn(s3,s3);
    N = randn(s1,s1,s3);

    funcs = {
        @() funcAlex(N,c)
        @() funcAmro(N,c)
    };
    t = cellfun(@timeit, funcs);
    v = cellfun(@feval, funcs, 'Uniform',false);
    norm(v{1}-v{2})
end

function M = funcAlex(N,c)
    [s1,~,s3] = size(N);
    M = zeros(s1*s1);
    for i=1:s3
        for j=1:s3
            M = M + c(i,j) .* kron(N(:,:,i), N(:,:,j));
        end
    end
end

function M = funcAmro(N,c)
    [s1,~,s3] = size(N);
    % tall matrix, NN = cat(1, N(:,:,1), ..., N(:,:,s3))
    NN = reshape(permute(N, [1 3 2]), s1*s3, s1);
    % accumulate kron results
    M = zeros(s1*s1*s3, s1*s1);
    for i=1:s3
        M = M + bsxfun(@times, repelem(c(:,i), s1*s1), kron(NN, N(:,:,i)));
    end
    % split M back into s3 slices each of size s1^2-by-s1^2
    M = permute(reshape(M.', s1*s1, s1*s1, s3), [2 1 3]);
    % sum along slices
    M = sum(M,3);
end
```

Using the sizes you mentioned (`N` is a 26-by-26-by-50 array), I get the following timings on my machine running R2016b:

```
>> t = testKron
t =
    3.2770    % funcAlex
    5.5119    % funcAmro
```

So my method is slower (not to mention less readable!). I guess all that permuting/reshaping has a non-negligible overhead..

Of course the resulting matrices `M` are equivalent (difference was `4.5801e-12` close to machine epsilon).

Comment: I should mention that my method timed faster when `s1` is small (e.g `s1=5; s3=50;` or `s1=5; s3=100;`)

Comment: Thanks for sharing the code. I have been playing a bit with both codes, and I have found out that the problem is not with the Kronecker products, but it is the summations what take forever. I am imagining that this has to do with the fact that some of the coefficients are variables of the Semidefinite Program solving package YALMIP that I'm using.

Comment: I'm not familiar with that package, but if the coefficients variable returned by the solver is not a regular "double matrix", you should convert as such outside the loops. Object indexing in MATLAB is a lot slower than native array indexing

Comment: @Alex: Also it just occurred to me that if you change the order of the for loops in your code `funcAlex` (go over `j` first then `i`) it might speed up the double-loop a tiny bit. This has to do with the fact that MATLAB stores `c` array in column-major order so it's [faster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality_of_reference) to access elements contiguously. Maybe even store a copy of the slice `N(:,:,j)` in the outer loop, to avoid repeated fetching of the same slice in the inner loop. Worth a try :)